# Generic casting confusion

Tags: c#, generics

I'm a little lost on casting generic types and wondering if anyone could please point out what I'm missing.

I have this abstract class definition:

```
public abstract class BaseEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
        ConfigureEntity(builder);

        var audited = builder as EntityTypeBuilder<IAuditedEntity>;
        audited?.ConfigureAudited();
        
        var timestamped = builder as EntityTypeBuilder<ITimestampEnabled>;
        timestamped?.ConfigureTimestamp();

        var softDelete = builder as EntityTypeBuilder<ISoftDelete>;
        softDelete?.ConfigureSoftDelete();

    }

    public abstract void ConfigureEntity(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder);

}
```

In my project this is invoked where TEntity is a Customer class which Implements IAuditedEntity and ITimestampEnabled.

How do I cast the `EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder` parameter to `EntityTypeBuilder<IAuditedEntity>`, etc?

Comment: Classes are invariant so you can't cast an `EntityTypeBuilder<Customer>` to a `EntityTypeBuilder<IAuditedEntity>`. You might be able to create an `IEntityTypeBuilder<out TEntity>` interface which allows you to convert an `EntityTypeBuilder<Customer>` to a `EntityTypeBuilder<IAuditedEntity>` depending on the operations it needs to support.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Given that Configure method is invoked from Entity Framework Core code can I declare a `IEntityTypeBuilder<out TEntity>` to make this work or am I stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the options I see is just make `ConfigureAudited` accept `EntityTypeBuilder` and not `EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>`. But this will complicate the entity setup and possibly make your code not type safe (though maybe it can be worked around using [`EntityTypeBuilder.Metadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.metadata?view=efcore-3.1) property).

Another option is reflection. You can move your configure methods to static classes (for convenience) and use them something like this:

```
public static class AuditedEntityExt
{
    public static void ConfigureAudited<T>(EntityTypeBuilder<T> tb) where T : class, IAuditedEntity
    {
        // entity setup
    }
}

public void Configure<T>(EntityTypeBuilder<T> tb) where T: class
{    
    if(typeof(IAuditedEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        typeof(AuditedEntityExt).GetMethod(nameof(AuditedEntityExt.ConfigureAudited))
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T))
            .Invoke(null, new[] { tb });
    }
}
```

Comment: Legend, thanks! I had extension methods for each interface and what you suggested works perfectly. I tend avoid reflection like the plague but I think this one of those situations where it makes sense. Once I get this deliverable finished I'll revisit the library and try to come up with a different design. Thanks again, I really appreciate your time.